# Do not allow unknown keys in nested object or array of objects using JOI?

Tags: joi

If an unknown field comes in the parent/root object then it throws the expected error. How to throw an error if there are any unknown fields in nested objects?

As per the [Joi object.unknown doc](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#objectunknownallow), it says *does not apply to children* so what should I use to get my expected results?

```
const obj = { 
  data: {
     center: "NY"
  },
  city: "tx",
  state: "us"
};

const schema = Joi.object({
  data: Joi.object({
     name: Joi.string().required()
  }).required(),
  city: Joi.string.required(),
  state: Joi.string.required(),
});

schema.validate(obj);

// outputs
name is required field

// expected output
name is required field
center is not allowed
```